# How to set Image on a button which supports iPhone and iPad in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ipad

i have a login button on my login view like following screen,  screen background is black. on login button using image or setting horizontal gradient i tried to set horizontal gradient but i can't do, so setting image i think it good option but is it correct to set with iPhone and iPad anyone having idea?

[image: login button image]

Comment: Yes, you can set image. Smartly created image with opacity at each end, which will allow background color to show up through button.

Comment: @Mr.UB but it is not showing correctly on ipad screen

Comment: Show how it is looking on iPad and how did you set it.

Comment: @Mr.UB    assume one login button present on base canvas and setted image of 600x 35 px image on top of that

Comment: first You should have both images (3x,2x) for All Device Support. after that you can manage using Aspect Ratio in Auto Layout.

Comment: To show it properly on iPhone and iPad, you have to use size classes. This is best solution and recommended by apple.

Comment: @PravinKamble please let me know in case of any query.

Comment: Just post the two picture of how you want it to look, both on iphone and ipad.